# Generating new variable after replacing values

Tags: database, windows, r

Hi I'm new to R and I would like to do something straightforward. I have missing values which R has as NA and I replaced them with the mean. With these values replaced, I want to create a new variable. Here's what I tried to get the new variable:

`mydata$xyz[is.na(mydata$xyz)] <- mean(mydata$xyz, na.rm = TRUE) = mydata$xyz2`

Appreciate the help!

Comment: user2220931, you should have a look at the [**SO about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page on asking questions and *accepting answers* if you find they answered your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mydata$xyz2 <- mydata$xyz
mydata$xyz2[is.na(mydata$xyz)] <- mean(mydata$xyz, na.rm = TRUE)
```